# How does reinterpret_cast work?

Tags: c++

Can someone explain how this code works and why?

```
int x = 0x1204;
char  v0 = *reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 3;
printf("%d   %x   %c \n", v0, v0, v0);
char  v3 = *(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 1) + 11;
printf("%d   %x   %c \n", v3, v3, v3);
short w4 = *(reinterpret_cast<short*>(&y) + 1) + 11;
printf("%x      %u       %d \n", w4, w4, w4);
long  w1 = *reinterpret_cast<long*>(&y) + 33;
printf("%lx     %lu     %ld \n", w1, w1, w1);
```

Here is my newbie version.

`char  v0 = *reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 3;
 printf("%d   %x   %c \n", v0, v0, v0);`

We are taking the address of `x` then casting its type from `int` to  `char`, dereferencing it, adding 3 to the address value and finally assigning to v0. 
How does it look in bits and bytes?

My guess is this. We are getting 4 bytes of int and after casting we will control the first bit (because of char size). After that we are dereferencing this bit and adding 3. Finally v0's value is bit + 3.

Does it looks something like this?

```
0001 0010 0000 0100 (int)
0001 (dereferenced char)
0100 (char + 3)
```

It would be nice if someone helped me to solve these 4 casts as an example.

Comment: You are lying to `printf`. The types you pass do not match the types in the format specifier. If you lie to `printf`, `printf` tends to print bad things.

Comment: we'll i got this as an example from my teacher

Comment: You deserve better teachers, then

Comment: This example is printed in documentation to my homework in university )

Comment: 1) "_adding 3 to address value_" - No, adding 3 to the dereferenced value (with integer addition). 2) Undefined behavior is undefined - no matter where you got such example from.

Comment: Many universities are ridiculously bad at teaching C and C++. (Life sucks, I know)

Comment: The versions with `short*` and `long*` are undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation. Also the latter may read out of bounds if `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 0x1204;
char  v0 = *reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 3;
```

You basically have it right, but I will break it down a little more.

```
int x
```

allocates 4 bytes of memory at some address to store an int value. (probably 4 bytes in most implementations)

```
= 0x1204;
```

assigns the hex value (0x prefix denotes hex) of 00 00 12 04 to the 4 bytes allocated for 'x'.  The order of the bytes is probably implementation specific.

We now have 4 bytes of memory allocated, with the values 00, 00, 12, and 04 in those bytes.  The variable x 'points' to those 4 bytes, and interprets the value as an integer.

In the next line, 
    &x
means "the address of x"

```
reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x)
```

means "look at what is at the address of x, as though we are looking at a character".  We know that x really points to 4 bytes of data that forms an integer.  This is a way of looking at the data in those 4 bytes one byte at a time.  We are looking at the 'first' byte now.

```
*reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x)
```

means "what is pointed to" by reinterpret_cast (&x).

```
*reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 3
```

means "add 3" to the character pointed to at the address of x.

```
char v0 = ....
```

means allocate a byte of memory at the address pointed to by v0, and assign the value we just calculated to that location.

Now, &x points to the 'first' byte of the 4 bytes of the int 'x'.  Which byte is the first byte is probably implementation specific.  In my case, &x reinterpret casted to a char actually points to the byte that contains the 4.  I am working on intel, Windows, VS2015.

As for the printf, I somewhat disagree that this is undefined behavior.  The char will implicitly convert to types being asked for in the printf statement.

```
printf("%d   %x   %c \n", v0, v0, v0);
```

We are asking to print the character at 'v0' 3 times.  Once as a decimal value (%d), once as a hex value (%x), and once as a character (%c).
In my case, the byte pointed to by the reinterpret cast contains the 4.  Adding 3 to the 4 gives 7.  This prints:

```
7  7
```

Since 7 hex is the bell character, I get a sound for the last value, and no printout.

If you are on motorola hardware, I suspect you might point to the other end of the int, which appears to be the assumption that you made in your analysis.

```
char  v3 = *(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&x) + 1) + 11;
```

This one is just a little different, in that it adds 1 to the address of x, which moves over by one byte. (because there are parens forcing the +1 to add 1 to the char pointer, which makes it point 1 character up from where it was pointing.)  Now in my implementation it points to the byte with '0x12' in it.  Adding decimal 11 to hex 12 yields the value 29 decimal, or 1d hex.

my output is 29  1d  (some unknown char that doesn't print properly)

As stated before, the value of y is not shown in your post...

Comment: It would be good to not talk of variable names as "pointing to" their contents, as that is easily confused with the concept of pointers. The usual term is to say that the variable name *designates* a memory location.  The result of dereferencing a pointer also designates a memory location.

Comment: One more question. Y is 0.48 double and i don`t know how much digits should i leave after decimal while transforming value into hex. Should it be 2 for  the size of byte ? Which precision is chosen by OS

Comment: A double will be 8 bytes in most instances.  Your exercise is going to look at the bytes that make up the double in integer formats (short and long), which don't have decimal places.  How a floating point number is represented is another subject that is somewhat complex.  You will see by looking at the data printed out that it is confusing.  see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format for some help...

Comment: @M.M - that is a useful clarification.  It is a struggle (at least for me) to word things exactly right.

Answer (score -1):

The intent of this exercice is to make so that you have a mental model of a machine. In C++, this simple mental model may help you, but you will have also to learn its limitations, latter (here there are implementation defined behaviour and "strict aliasing rule" violations)

Sorry!!! In fact this is certainly: (char must be 8 bit!)

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0010 0000 0100 (int)
0000 0000 (dereferenced char)
0000 0100 (char + 3)
0000 0100 0000 0000 0001 0010 0000 0100 (int after char + 3)

//the second:
          char[1]
0000 0100 0000 0000 0001 0010 0000 0100 (int)
0000 0000 (dereferenced char[1])
0000 1011 (char + 11)
0000 0100 0000 1011 0001 0010 0000 0100 (int after char + 11)
//then I do not know what is y!!
```